# How to use C++ API in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, api

I need to embed an API written in C++ in .NET that is used by a Fingerprint device into a .NET application.

I tried with both languages VB.NET and C# but still I'm unable to understand the issue its giving me;

```
Unable to find the entry point in the DLL.
```

That means its accessing the DLL, but what is the issue can you please tell me?

Here is the sample Code:

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    const string _dllLocation = "ABCAPI.dll";
    [DllImport(_dllLocation, EntryPoint = "ABCFunc", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl    )]
    public static extern bool ABCFunc();
}
```

Comment: do you have access to the header file in the C++ where this entry point lives?

Comment: Whatever the real name of the function might be, your ExactSpelling = True is not going to help find it.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see the exported names.  And keep in mind that you generally cannot pinvoke C++ functions, the kind that are instance functions of a C++ class.  That requires a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: @HansPassant , 
Well, I'm Un-aware of dumpbin.exe 's use and i don't know how to use it, can you please tell me how i should use it and how to write a wrapper ?
any good reff. of basic level???

and i tried it with different options nothing works
i.e.


`    **[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("DuoPassCSAPI.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool InitDuoPass();**   `

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ABCAPI.dll", SetLastError = true)]  
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]  
public static extern bool ABCFunc();
```

Comment: Yes i have all the files for it and Header files / SDK etc too, but dnt know how to implement it :(

Comment: I have tried as you refer but still getting the same error.

Comment: You don't need the header files. Just make sure that the DLL is accessible (is in PATH) and is a valid application.

Comment: Its is accessing the Dll file, otherwise error description shold be something like unable to find dll etc??
i put it in debug folder in the application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks   @ Hans Passant 
I have made a research and Use 
" dumpbin /Exports mydllname.dll "
and find the actuall declaration of the functions and that finally works for me.

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods {
const string _dllLocation = "ABCAPI.dll";
[DllImport(_dllLocation, EntryPoint = "_ABCFunc@4", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall    )]
public static extern bool ABCFunc();
```

}

and it works perfectly all right , Thanks for the suggestion.